# Translations calculated using matrices

Tags: matrices

You have used matrices to calculate the results of certain rotations and reflections. Which ones? Are translations calculated using matrices?

I know of the different types of reflections, like across the x-axis, y-axis, origin, and y=x, but I haven’t heard of using matrices to calculate translations… does someone mind explaining to me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, translations can't be computed via the same matrix-multiplication process.

The reason is that matrix multiplication will always map the vector $\vec0$ to itself, whereas a translation doesn't (except when the translation vector is $\vec0$ itself).

For all $a,b,c,d,\qquad$
$$\pmatrix{a & b \\c & d\\}\pmatrix{0 \\0 \\}=\pmatrix{0 \\0 \\}$$
But $$\pmatrix{0 \\0 \\}+\vec v=\vec v$$

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot, but why does it result in the vector when the matrix is added? @arnaud mortier

Comment: @PatriciaM. In the $2\times 2$ matrix case above, the matrix isn't added, [it's multiplied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). Just like in the case of rotations and reflections. [See also this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html) perhaps more readable for a first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to describe a translation in say $\mathbb{R}^2$ you may use a $3\times3$ matrix as follows:

For a translation by a vector $\vec{x}=(a,b)$ , $T_{\vec{x}}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & b \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

So $T_{\vec{x}}\cdot (\alpha,\beta,1)^t=(a+\alpha,b+\beta,1)$ which is like $(\alpha,\beta)+\vec{x}=(a+\alpha,b+\beta)$